# Highcharts/Highstock DataGrouping & Approximation

Tags: highcharts

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.approximation

I don't mind that highcharts is data grouping my data. What i do mind is that i can not seem to bring back a flag saying if it is currently active on the zoom level or not.

If there is data grouping, i want to bring back that information for the user to tell them this is not the exact data, and that there is some approximation that is occurring.

When i zoom in, the data grouping stops and approximation does not exist any more and i see the accurate data, and i want to tell users that no approximation is being doing right now.

I haven't been able to find a way of bringing this infomration forward to the user, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seems that the object you are looking for is currentDataGrouping.
You can access it using i.e. `chart.series[0].currentDataGrouping`.

If data grouping is not active then currentDataGrouping will be null.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/c3wr3gss/